# How to re-render google map in react upon state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm trying to integrate the JavaScript Maps API with React.js following this guide:

http://cuneyt.aliustaoglu.biz/en/using-google-maps-in-react-without-custom-libraries/

I can get the map to load fine and everything works great. The issue I'm having is that I can't get the map to re-render when the state changes.

Essentially, I am using the following code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-67pggp?file=index.js

Except, I'm trying to dynamically change the position of the marker with a state change. So, in the onMapLoad() function passed to the Map component, I replace the line

`position: { lat: 41.0082, lng: 28.9784 }`

with something along the lines of

`position: { lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng }`

and I want the position of the marker to change whenever the position stored in the state changes. I know that the issue stems from the fact that onMapLoad() is only called when the component first mounts, but I'm unsure of how to get the map to re-render and show the updated marker position. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  One of the norms here is for question authors to include their code directly in the question, as opposed to pasting a link to the code.  This makes the question more readable, easier for others to find via search engine queries, and easier for experts to answer (since they don't have to navigate off the page).  Please consider editing your question to reflect this best practice.

Answer (score -1):

You can use getInitialState method for initializing the default state and use this variable in render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Map from './map'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
   getInitialState() {
    return {
       lat = '41.0082',
       lng = '28.9784'
     };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        id="myMap"
        options={{
          center: { lat : this.state.lat ,lng : this.state.lng },
          zoom: 8
        }}
        onMapLoad={map => {
          var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat :this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng },
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello Istanbul!'
          });
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all, read the title again